# Receiving input from various actionbuttons in Shiny R

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shiny-server

So this is somehow a follow up to my previous: [Automatic GUI Generating in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226627/automatic-gui-generating-in-r-shiny) wher I posted the solution to how to generate elements iteratively.

Now I am unable to recieve/check which actionbuttons have been pressed and perform some action upon press.

In general, there is a function that generates the buttons and sends it to the ui.R:

```
output$generateImages <- renderUI({
  (...)
  i <-1
  for(dir in folders){
    (...)
    txt<-paste0("rep",i)
    pp<-pathNameToImage
    LL[[i]] <- list(actionButton(txt,icon=imageOutput(pp,width="100px",height="100px"),label=dir))
    i<-i+1
  }
return(LL)          
  }
```

in ui.R I have:

```
uiOutput('generateImages')
```

And it displays the buttons fine by accumulating them into the list called "LL".

I have tried looking for tutorials and examples but was not able to find how it is done with images, and how to later recieve input from buttons that were not created "by hand", but iteratively.

How do I access these buttons in "observe" so that I can perform a action? I have tried input$generateImages, input$LL and few others, but all of them had a value of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to access them by their unique ID. The [first argument](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/actionButton.html) passed to actionButton is its ID. That's what you'll need to use to get it as input.

So:

```
LL[[i]] <- list(actionButton("SomeID"))
```

when you assign it, then

```
input[["SomeID"]]
```

when you want to reference it. Of course, you can use a variable instead of a hardcoded string for the ID.

Comment: Hey. This is what I am trying to do:      

    if(input[["rep1"]]){
            print(2)
          }

And I get: " Error in if (input[["rep1"]]) { : argument is of length "

Comment: Any idea how to do this iteratively?